# Graph Theory - Clarification of type of graph

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Just wondering if somebody can confirm the following:

1. If I have some number of verticies, if there is only one edge connecting two of the vertices, can this be a bipartite graph, or do all verticies need to be connected to make it a biartite graph?
2. If I have a graph, lets say 1-2-4-1-3, can this be a tree?  My understanding is that it can not be a tree if it contains a cycle, but doesn't a cycle start and finish at the same vertix?  I'm thinking it is a tree anyway.

I've been searching for these answers for the last hour.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. A graph is bipartite if you can divide the vertices into two groups such that all the edges go from one group to the other.  A bipartite graph might not have any edges; a graph with only one edge is always bipartite.

   If *every* vertex in the first group is connected to *every* vertex in the other group, the graph is a "complete" bipartite graph. But not all bipartite graphs are complete.
2. A graph is a tree if it does not *contain* a cycle.  If a graph contains a configuration like 1-2-4-1-3, then it also contains 1-2-4-1, which is a cycle, so the graph is not a tree.

I hope this clears up your questions.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much.

Comment: Nitpick:  a nonconnected graph with no cycles is often called a "forest".  I don't know if this definition is universal.